# Oracle Apex- Copy URL of page on button click

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a region button on application page called copy url.

I need to create a dynamic action such that when the button is clicked, using javascript or any other expression the current url of the page is copied.

I tried creating one but not sure what should i write in the expression part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there's the `P13_URL` item on the page and the button which - when clicked - populates the item with current URL.

Button's dynamic action would then be

- action: execute JavaScript code
- code: `document.getElementById("P13_URL").value = document.URL;`
- affected items: `P13_URL`

That's all.